# How can I call methods on a GObject class written in C from python?

Tags: python, c, glib, pygobject, gobject-introspection

I am trying to create a GObject class in C and annotate it in a way, so that I can use the class from Python - but I think am missing something, since I get weird errors that I can't understand. Any help would be much appreciated!

The class works as expected if I try to use it from other C-code, and I can generate both the `.gir` and `.typelib` files and as far as I can tell, the XML looks correct.

When I try to create instances of the class from Python, it appears that the `_class_init` and `_init` functions for the object isn't called, and I get exceptions if I try to call methods:

```py
from gi.repository import Bop
foo = Bop.FooObj()
foo.get_number_of_tap_dancers()
# TypeError: expected GObject but got <gi.repository.Bop.FooObj object at 0x104670100>
```

I have tried to explicitly create a constructor for my class (`bop_foo_obj_new`) and if I call that from Python, I can see both the `_class_init` and `_init` get functions gets called, but then the Python interpreter segfaults:

```
Bop.FooObj.new()
# bop_foo_obj_new() called!!!!
# bop_foo_obj_class_init() called!!!!
# bop_foo_obj_init() called!!!!
#
# ** (process:25468): CRITICAL **: 12:55:19.436: pygobject_register_wrapper: assertion # 'PyObject_TypeCheck(self, &PyGObject_Type)' failed
# ./wat.sh: line 4: 25468 Segmentation fault: 11  GI_TYPELIB_PATH=build LD_LIBRARY_PATH=build python ./wat.py
```

---

Here is the code I am trying to get to work:

**bop.h:**

```c
#pragma once
#include <glib-object.h>

G_BEGIN_DECLS

G_DECLARE_DERIVABLE_TYPE(BopFooObj, bop_foo_obj, BOP, FOO_OBJ, GObject);

struct _BopFooObjClass {
  GObjectClass parent;
};

BopFooObj *bop_foo_obj_new();
guint32 bop_foo_obj_get_number_of_tap_dancers(BopFooObj *self);

G_END_DECLS
```

**bop.c:**

```c
#include "bop.h"
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  guint tap_dancer_cnt;
} BopFooObjPrivate;

G_DEFINE_TYPE_WITH_PRIVATE(BopFooObj, bop_foo_obj, G_TYPE_OBJECT);

static void bop_foo_obj_class_init(BopFooObjClass *klass) {
  fprintf(stderr, "bop_foo_obj_class_init() called!!!!\n");
}

static void bop_foo_obj_init(BopFooObj *self) {
  fprintf(stderr, "bop_foo_obj_init() called!!!!\n");
  BopFooObjPrivate *priv = bop_foo_obj_get_instance_private(self);
  priv->tap_dancer_cnt = 9999;
}

/**
 * bop_foo_obj_new:(constructor):
 * Returns:(transfer full):
 */
BopFooObj *bop_foo_obj_new() {
  fprintf(stderr, "bop_foo_obj_new() called!!!!\n");
  return BOP_FOO_OBJ(g_object_new(bop_foo_obj_get_type(), NULL));
}

/**
 * bop_foo_obj_get_number_of_tap_dancers:
 * @self: the #BopFooObj instance
 */
guint32 bop_foo_obj_get_number_of_tap_dancers(BopFooObj *self) {
  BopFooObjPrivate *priv = bop_foo_obj_get_instance_private(self);
  return priv->tap_dancer_cnt;
}
```

**Generated .gir file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- This file was automatically generated from C sources - DO NOT EDIT!
To affect the contents of this file, edit the original C definitions,
and/or use gtk-doc annotations.  -->
<repository version="1.2"
            xmlns="http://www.gtk.org/introspection/core/1.0"
            xmlns:c="http://www.gtk.org/introspection/c/1.0"
            xmlns:glib="http://www.gtk.org/introspection/glib/1.0">
  <namespace name="Bop"
             version="0.1"
             shared-library="libwat.dylib"
             c:identifier-prefixes="Bop"
             c:symbol-prefixes="bop">
    <class name="FooObj"
           c:symbol-prefix="foo_obj"
           c:type="BopFooObj"
           glib:type-name="BopFooObj"
           glib:get-type="bop_foo_obj_get_type"
           glib:type-struct="FooObjClass">
      <source-position filename="../bop.h" line="10"/>
      <constructor name="new" c:identifier="bop_foo_obj_new">
        <source-position filename="../bop.h" line="12"/>
        <return-value transfer-ownership="full">
          <type name="FooObj" c:type="BopFooObj*"/>
        </return-value>
      </constructor>
      <method name="get_number_of_tap_dancers"
              c:identifier="bop_foo_obj_get_number_of_tap_dancers">
        <source-position filename="../bop.h" line="13"/>
        <return-value transfer-ownership="none">
          <type name="guint32" c:type="guint32"/>
        </return-value>
        <parameters>
          <instance-parameter name="self" transfer-ownership="none">
            <doc xml:space="preserve"
                 filename="../bop.c"
                 line="31">the #BopFooObj instance</doc>
            <type name="FooObj" c:type="BopFooObj*"/>
          </instance-parameter>
        </parameters>
      </method>
      <field name="parent_instance" introspectable="0">
        <type c:type="GObject"/>
      </field>
    </class>
    <record name="FooObjClass"
            c:type="BopFooObjClass"
            glib:is-gtype-struct-for="FooObj">
      <source-position filename="../bop.h" line="10"/>
      <field name="parent" introspectable="0">
        <type c:type="GObjectClass"/>
      </field>
    </record>
  </namespace>
</repository>
```

Comment: Can you post a copy of the GIR XML for the class please? Often problems are diagnosable by looking at that. Please also post a copy of the compile commands/build script you’re using, and the commands you’re using to run the Python code.

Comment: sure! I updated the post

Comment: @PhilipWithnall The build tool I am using i Meson, and thanks to your comment I started look even closer at what it actually creates. The XML was missing `           parent="GObject.Object"` on my class, and this turned out to be because I had to add `includes: 'GObject-2.0'` to the `gnome.generate_gir` section of my `meson.build` file.

Thank you :-)

Comment: And that fixed it? If so, great! It would be helpful for others if you wrote your solution up (and marked it as the solution to the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem caused by the way the build system I am using, Meson, was calling `g-ir-scanner`. I noticed that it was using `--extra-library=GObject-2.0` while the few tutorials I could find on this subject was calling `g-ir-scanner` with `--include=GObject-2.0`.

I added `includes: 'GObject-2.0'` to the `gnome.generate_gir` section of my `meson.build` file and that fixed the problem:

The final meson.build file looks like this:

```
project('wat', 'c', default_options : ['c_std=c17'])

gnome = import('gnome')
deps = [
  dependency('gobject-2.0'),
  dependency('gobject-introspection-1.0')
]

headers = [
  'bop.h'
]
sources = [
  'bop.c'
]

wat_lib = library('wat',
    sources,
    dependencies: deps,
    install: true,
)

gnome.generate_gir(
    wat_lib,
    namespace: 'Bop',
    nsversion: '0.1',
    sources: headers + sources,
    dependencies: deps,
    install: true,
    fatal_warnings: true,
    includes: 'GObject-2.0',   # this line fixed the issue.
)
```